# Specified Tab Order is not being followed?

Tags: wpf, xaml, focus, tab-ordering

Why isn't my XAML following the TabOrder I specified?

I currently have:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <UserControl TabIndex="0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox />
                <TextBox Text="Search Text" />
                <Button Content="Search" />
            </StackPanel>
        </UserControl>
        <ComboBox TabIndex="1" />
        <Separator />
        <TextBox TabIndex="3" Text="Save" />
        <TextBox TabIndex="4" Text="Cancel" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl TabIndex="2" />
        <Popup />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

[image]

My TabOrder should go

- Search ComboBox
- Search Text
- Search Button
- Database ComboBox
- ContentControl
- Save Button
- Cancel Button

But instead it goes

- Search ComboBox
- Search Text
- Search Button
- **ContentControl**
- **Database ComboBox**
- Save Button
- Cancel Button

What do I have wrong with my TabOrder?

**Edit**

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556343/wpf-tab-order-working-wrong) which suggested making `UserControl.IsTabStop="False"`, and binding it's Child control's TabIndex to `UserControl.TabIndex`, which partially works.

My TabOrder is now

- Search ComboBox
- Search Text
- Search Button
- Database ComboBox
- Save Button
- Cancel Button
- **ContentControl**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently by default, WPF reads all the controls, inside and outside UserControls, at the same tab level (unless specified otherwise). Since the controls inside the UserControl do not have a TabIndex specified, they get tabbed to last after the first tab cycle.

The workaround was to bind the `TabIndex` of the inner controls to the `TabIndex` of the UserControl

```
<DockPanel Margin="10" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          local:GridProperties.ColumnCount="6"
          local:GridProperties.StarColumns="0">

        <TextBlock Text="Header" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False" Content="{Binding SearchViewModel}" />

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" Width="100" />

        <Separator Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource VerticalSeparatorStyle}" />

        <Button Grid.Column="4" TabIndex="3" Content="Save" Width="75" Margin="5" />
        <Button Grid.Column="5" TabIndex="4" Content="Cancel" Width="75" Margin="5" />
    </Grid>

    <Line HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" X2="1" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0,5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />

    <Grid x:Name="ShellContentRoot">

        <!-- Current Page -->
        <ContentControl TabIndex="2" Content="{Binding CurrentAccount}" IsTabStop="False" />

        <!-- Search Results -->
        <local:PopupPanel local:PopupPanel.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=ShellContentRoot}" />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

The only thing special about my `SearchView` is that the controls all set

```
TabIndex="{Binding Path=TabIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type local:SearchView}}}"
```

Tab Order goes:

- UserControl Search ComboBox
- UserControl Search Text
- UserControl Search Button
- Database ComboBox
- ContentControl
- Save Button
- Cancel Button

Answer (score 0):

Try including KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" in your parent DockPanel.

```
<DockPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
```

[KeyboardNavigationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode.aspx)

Comment: I don't want local Tab navigation though... I want the first Grid to have TabIndex 0, 1, 3, 4, and the second grid to have TabIndex 2

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 <DockPanel  >
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
         <UserControl TabIndex="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox />
                <TextBox Text="Search Text" />
                <Button Content="Search" />
            </StackPanel>
         </UserControl>
         <ComboBox TabIndex="1"  DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
         <Separator />
         <TextBox TabIndex="3" Text="Save"  DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
         <TextBox TabIndex="4" Text="Cancel" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
          <ContentControl TabIndex="2"  Height="100" Width="100"/>
          <Popup />
    </Grid>
 </DockPanel>
```

Comment: I don't want Local Keyboard Navigation though inside my UserControl. I want it to Cycle