# elements' tab key press order

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some of `TextBox` in my application. Now that I copied most of it, it's in a strange order when filling in data and pressing the `TAB` key. How can I adjust this order?

Comment: I tried looking through the element's properties but found nothing I could make use of.

Comment: thanks for downvoting

Comment: that really helped me a lot

Comment: It's called the [`TabIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359758/setting-tab-order-in-wpf and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556343/wpf-tab-order-working-wrong. Tab order in WPF is somewhat more complicated than in Winforms, but you have more control over the specifics as well. See these related posts and others for lots of details.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your controls' [TabIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That link is for WinForm's TabIndex, not for WPFs - see my comment for the WPF link.

Comment: Sorry, didnt see your comment. 

The property name is the same. Here we just give tips how to solve it.